# Inverse of an almost Orthogonal Matrix

Tags: matrices

**Background:**

I have a tridiagonal matrix that is almost but not quite symmetric. Consequently, its eigenvectors are not orthogonal and neither therefore, is the matrix of (column) eigenvectors that I need to invert to get the Jordan Normal form for the solution of the underlying ODE system.

**Issue:**

If the eigenvector matrix were orthogonal, the inverse would've been the transpose, but since it isn't, I have to formally invert the matrix for which column-by-column Gaussian Elimination works, but is expensive.

**Question:**

I was wondering if there is a less expensive method of finding the inverse, if I could start with $\bf X^{-1}=X^T$ as the initial guess and converge to $\bf XX^{-1}=I$.